# How to get shipping price after shipping method has been selected on Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to get the shipping cost via an observer that is triggered on the event:

```
checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method
```

I used this code in Magento 1.7:

```
$shipping = 
Mage::helper('core')->currency($shippingMethod['shipping_amount'],true,false);
```

but it does not seem to work now (always returns zero).

In addition, the following code:

```
$total = $quote->getTotals()['grand_total']->getData('value');
```

returns only the total to be paid without the shipping cost.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the deal:
You need the collectTotals method in order for the whole thing to work (get totals with shipping cost).
Here is what I've used:

```
$total = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->collectTotals()->getTotals()['grand_total']->getData('value');
```